# Execute on PageLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I execute this code in HTML on page load?

```
<script>    
    window.onload = $(function(){
        $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
};
</script>
```

I have tried this code but it does not work.

Comment: directly write in script. http://jsfiddle.net/9LXRB/ no need to write `onload` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
   $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

or `document.ready()` if you aren't waiting for particular elements to load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have an extra `$(` that you don't need, and a missing closing `}`...

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
};
```

Although that gets your code working, you could probably run this when the DOM is ready (which is quicker than waiting for all the images to load)...

```
$(function() {
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this when you only want to access your DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* code */ });

$(function() { /* code */ }); // shorthand function (is identical)
```

If you require all other resources (styles, scripts, iframes, images, etc.) to be loaded too (eg. get an image dimensions), you need to use this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { /* code */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up JavaScript's way of doing things with jQuery's way of doing things.

Using `windows.onload = ...` is how you assign a function to be called after the load event occurs in JavaScript.

Using `$(function(){...})` is jQuery syntax for `$(document).ready(function(){})` which essentialy is the same thing, jQuery's document ready also triggers after load but unlike unlike `windows.onload` before images are loaded.

Use one or the other syntax.

Either use JavaScript like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
}
```

Or one of jQuery's alternatives:

```
$(function(){
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
})
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
})
```

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close your function codeblock like this.

```
<script>    
    window.onload = $(function(){
        $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This, Remove window.OnLoad

```
$(function(){
    $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

**SEE DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/qgPzG/

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax:

```
$(function(){
  $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
window.onload = function () {
// do stuff here
  $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close " **});** " :

```
<script>    
    window.onload = $(function(){
        $("#name1, #name2").val("").attr("disabled",true);
 });
</script>
```